# Custom keras generator __get_item__() is called more than __len__()

Tags: python, deep-learning, tf.keras

I've built a custom keras generator.function. 
It yields an img and associated gt.
It works well for the training phase with predict_generator() function.

To evaluate my model, I use it on a test set containing 592 images. I call it with the predict_generator() function.
So I get the right number of prediction (592). Every time **get_item**() function is called, I add the GT to the self.gt list.

Then, after running predict_generator(), I compare the predictions with the stored GT.

**My problem :
I want to store ground truth array in a list, everytime the generator is called. But at the end, I have more GT_arrays than the 592 predictions.
So I can't build my confusion matrix...**

Here is the code of the generator:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, data_folders_txt, gen_data_type, batchsize, shuffle=True, classes=None, selected_class=None):

        '''
        - data_fodlers_txt : txt_file containing all the paths to different folders of data
        - gen_type : string : can be either "train", "val" or "test" (correspond to a specific folder)
        - shuffle : Shuffle the dataset at each epoch
        - classes : dict of classes with associated nb (class nb must match the class position on the class axis of the ground truth one-hot-encoded array)
        - selected_class : name of the selected class (128x128x1) in the 128x128x3 ground truth one-hot-encoded array
        '''

        self.gt = []
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.gen_data_type = gen_data_type
        self.batchsize = batchsize
        self.data_folders = open(data_folders_txt, "r").readlines()
        self.list_IDs = self.tiles_list_creation(self.data_folders)
        self.samples = len(self.list_IDs)
        self.classes = classes
        self.selected_class = selected_class
        self.index = 0
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def tiles_list_creation(self, list_folders):
        list_IDs = []
        for folder in list_folders:
            samples = glob.glob(folder.rstrip() + self.gen_data_type + '3/tile/*')
            list_IDs += samples
        random.shuffle(list_IDs)
        return list_IDs

    def __len__(self):
        if len(self.list_IDs) % self.batchsize == 0:
            return len(self.list_IDs)//self.batchsize
        else:
            return len(self.list_IDs) // self.batchsize + 1

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        self.index = index
        X = []
        y = []
        # min(...,...) is for taking all the data without being out of range
        for i in range(index*self.batchsize, min(self.samples, (index+1)*self.batchsize)):

            tile = np.load(self.list_IDs[i])

            #If specific class is specified, just take the right channel of the GT_array corresponding to the wanted class 
            if self.classes:
                gt = np.load(self.list_IDs[i].replace("tile", "gt"))[:, :, self.classes[self.selected_class]]
                gt = np.expand_dims(gt, axis=-1)
            else:
                gt = np.load(self.list_IDs[i].replace("tile", "gt"))

            #store ground truth to compare the values between gt and predictions after running predict_generator()
            self.gt.append(gt)

            X.append(tile)
            y.append(gt)

        return np.array(X), np.array(y)

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.shuffle:
            random.shuffle(self.list_IDs)
```

And here is where I call it:

```
batchsize = 10

model = load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'jaccard_distance': jaccard_distance, 'auc': auc})

test_gen = DataGenerator("/path/to/data/path/written/in/file.txt",
                         gen_data_type='test',
                         batchsize=batchsize,
                         classes=None,
                         selected_class=None)
y_pred = model.predict_generator(test_gen, steps=None, verbose=1)
y_true = np.array(test_gen.gt)


plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, ["Hedgerows", "No Hedgerows"])
```

Here is the error:

```
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 71ms/step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/work/stages/mathurin/sentinel_segmentation/unet/confusion_matrix.py", line 95, in <module>
    plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, ["Hedgrows", "No Hedgerows"], normalize=normalization, title=model_path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0])
  File "/work/stages/mathurin/sentinel_segmentation/unet/confusion_matrix.py", line 35, in plot_confusion_matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/work/tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 253, in confusion_matrix
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/work/tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 71, in _check_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/work/tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 235, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [702, 592]
```

when I look at the index number of the **get_item**() function, it is not the  expected number... It should be the number returned by the **len**() function but it is always smaller.
In this example, after making the predictions, the self.index parameter value is **8**.
Like if it was exceeding then restarting at 0, 1, 2, etc...

**EDIT: more strange !**
I just re-run and I get a different number of stored_gt arrays ...

```
60/60 [==============================] - 6s 100ms/step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/work/tools/pycharm-community-2019.1.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "/work/tools/pycharm-community-2019.1.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/work/tools/pycharm-community-2019.1.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/work/tools/pycharm-community-2019.1.1/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/work/stages/mathurin/sentinel_segmentation/unet/confusion_matrix.py", line 95, in <module>
    plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, ["Hedgrows", "No Hedgerows"], normalize=normalization, title=model_path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0])
  File "/work/stages/mathurin/sentinel_segmentation/unet/confusion_matrix.py", line 35, in plot_confusion_matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/work/tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 253, in confusion_matrix
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/work/tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 71, in _check_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/work/tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 235, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [682, 592]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strange in this, generators are run by keras using multiple processes/threads to improve performance, specially for training, that's why `fit_generator` and `predict_generator` have keyword arguments like `workers`, `use_multiprocessing`, `max_queue_size`. So the solution is not to store any kind of ground truth or state in the generator instance.

For your specific case, you can use another kind of prediction loop, by calling the generator manually:

```
labels = []
preds = []
for step in range(len(generator)):
    data, label = generator.__getitem__(step)
    pred = model.predict(data)

    preds.append(pred)
    labels.append(label)
```

Then using `preds` and `labels` to make a confusion matrix.